# How to search a keyword in Eclipse type search

Tags: eclipse

How can I do a keyword search in Eclipse Types.

When doing a search using the eclipse, the system is doing the search in all the java files I have in my workspace but does not do a search in the classes I have in the JARs I have in my workspace.

Following is the search term:

```
Cannot initialize the modules because I can't guess which module to mount
to '/' at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.wireModules(Butterfly.java:821)
```

I tried doing this, but of no use. For better understanding attaching the images:
[image]

I can't figure out from which jar file type, this string is coming. As we can do a global search on the .java files. Is there a way, we can do keywood search for the jar types(jar file content .class) as well in Eclipse.

Or that is not even possible as suggested by @nitind.

Comment: If screenshots are required for better understanding then I can attach those if needed.

Comment: Class files are binaries, not searchable source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no Eclipse plugin/configuration/setup that can perform this operation.

Although it is possible to search a jar by writing a simple utility like this:

```
URL url = FindResourceMain.class.getResource("/" + filePath);
```

We can also use, utility tools like [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) to perform a global search in jar/zip.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "a keyword search in Eclipse Types".  If I had to guess, I think you mean that you're looking for a type that has a particular word in the name.

You can do this by first doing the "Open Type" operation from the menu bar or from a keyboard shortcut.  For example, if you want to find all of the types that have "Basket" in the name of the type, then enter "*Basket*" in the search field in the "Open Type" dialog.